# Spring Integration - File Adapter not working after first attempt

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Been running into some issues with File Adapter in Spring Integration and have no idea as I never heard about this before. Using the below code to read a file from FTP folder and write it to the local directory.

Problem is after the server is started, it works fine for the first time. But the subsequent invocations invoke the file adapter but the file moving process isn't happening.

Cron Timing is : 0/20 * * * * ?.

Any idea about this weird behavior?

```
<int:channel id="txtFilesIn">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="txtFilesOut">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
    </int:channel>  

     <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="txtFilesIn"
        directory="${FILE_IN}"
        filename-pattern="*.csv"
         auto-startup="true">
        <int:poller cron="${CRON_TAB}" ></int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="txtFilesIn"
                           output-channel="txtFilesOut" 
                           ref="apiCommonService" 
                           method="readFile"/>

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="txtFilesOut"
        directory="${FILE_OUT}"
        delete-source-files="true"/>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Modified like this

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="txtFilesIn"
        directory="${FILE_IN}"            
         auto-startup="true"
     local-filter="acceptAll">
        <int:poller cron="${CRON_TAB}" ></int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="acceptAll" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter" />
```

It is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`:

> A `FileReadingMessageSource` can be used to consume files from the
>    filesystem. This is an implementation of MessageSource that creates
>    messages from a file system directory.
>
> To prevent creating messages for certain files, you may supply a `FileListFilter`. By default the following 2 filters are used:
>
> - `IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter`
> - `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`

So, that's correct that it picks up files from the first time, but it doesn't do anything any subsequent times if there is no any new files matching the filter.

Comment: The file adapter runs once every 10 minutes and I just placed a file again in the IN folder. This should work, and that is why the polling is there, IIRC! But it isn't happening and I don't know why!

Comment: ` I just placed a file again` . That is important part (!!!). See `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. It doesn't allow to process the same file again. The filtering logic is based in the file name. So, you have to place file with different name or disable this `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` from the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` as far as I see you use `delete-source-files="true"` on the outbound side.

Comment: Modified the code with acceptAllFilter and it works fine. Thanks for the help.